# Holomorphic function taking all values near a singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

I recall a theorem in complex analysis about a holomorphic function having to take all different possible values in the neighbourhood of a singularity. Can someone point me to the name of this theorem please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably thinking of [(Great) Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem):

> Great Picard's Theorem: If an analytic function $f$ has an essential
> singularity at a point $w$, then on any punctured neighborhood of $w$, $f(z)$ takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single
> exception, infinitely often.